# I cannot display dynamic page title using spring 3 and apache tiles 2.2

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I have a problem using spring 3 and tiles 2.2.2 . I can't display a dynamic page title.
These are my config/jsp files:

**layout.jsp**

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" ignore="true"/></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        <div id="content-outer">
            <div id="content-wrapper" class="container_16">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Spring config file:**

```
<bean id="tilesviewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext" />
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="tilesProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.apache.tiles.evaluator.AttributeEvaluator">org.apache.tiles.evaluator.el.ELAttributeEvaluator
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/views/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/inc/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/inc/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/inc/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="item/itemDetail" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="%{title}"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/item/itemDetail.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

the page title isn't replaced with title value rendered by controller, instead %{title}.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post the controller?

Comment: you are using a tiles feature that I never noticed, can you please add a hint to the part of the documentation that explain how the "title" variable can be used in a tiles definition.

Answer (score 6):

I think that your page definition should look like this (note the 'expression' attribute and '$' instead of '%'):

```
<definition name="item/itemDetail" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" expression="${title}"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/item/itemDetail.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Are you sure that there is an attribute called ${title} in a relevant scope? Have you tried rendering the value of ${title} directly in the itemDetail.jsp page?

Here's the relevant documentation, tiles uses the servlet container's EL support for this:
http://tiles.apache.org/2.1/framework/tutorial/advanced/el-support.html.